# snackbar - очередь

Tags: java, android

Понадобился следующий функционал:

Пользователь должен наблюдать как снизу друг за другом лезут `SnackBar`ы, образуя очередь (максимум, 4). Пробовал в цикле создавать 4 `SnackBar`a, но это не работает. Ах, да, и еще нужно заменить анимации появления и исчезновения `SnackBar` с экрана. Где на эту тему можно почитать (язык неважен), или здесь только создавать класс, наследовать от `SnackBar` и писать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для создания *очереди* из `SnackBar`, можете, например, помещать очередь в колекцию (`Queue`?), а чтобы показывать одну за другой - можете использовать параметр `duration` равный `LENGTH_INDEFINITE` (доступен с версии 22.2.1 Support-library):

```
Snackbar.make(parentLayout, "че-то там", LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
```

А по таймауту прятать данный `SnackBar`, и показывать следующий в очереди.

Comment: thanks! great solution :)